# Upgrading laptop processor

Tags: laptop, cpu, upgrade, dell-studio

I have a Dell Studio 17. It's a few years old, and I wanted to upgrade the processor. It currently has an Intel Core 2 Duo T5750 @ 2.00GHz

My question is how can I find out which processors are compatible?

Answer (score 5):

It is very rare that a laptop processor can be upgraded. The CPU and the cooling arrangement tends to be permanently fixed to the mainboard. Even if the part *is* replaceable getting into it can be difficult, requiring you strip down the whole machine, and you will have difficulty finding the new CPU - you can't just slap a standard desktop CPU in there and I'm not aware of any general suppliers that sell mobile CPUs on their own in this way.

Comment: +1, I find that is one of the major donwsides to a laptop. It's easier to replace the whole lapto than spending money to get that laptop upgraded.

Comment: +1, There are only a couple consumer upgradeable parts in a laptop and the CPU is not one of them. There are other options for performance increases though if that's your main goal. A new question related to that might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to what your motherboard will support.  Dell may or may not be able to answer this for you.  There is anecdotal evidence [here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductReview.aspx?Item=N82E16819111006) of swapping a T5750 for a T9600.  Without having detailed info of your board at hand I can't guarantee anything, but you should be able to upgrade it to some degree.  I would venture you should be able to use just about any Core 2 socket P processor.

Certainly installation isn't going to be as easy as a desktop system, so it depends on your comfort level for that. I think the answer that it being rare they can be upgraded is rather false.  It is difficult, but it regularly CAN be done.  Do note that some laptops will have processors soldered onto the board.  By all means those would fall into the category of non-upgradable.

[Newegg](http://www.newegg.com) as well as other vendors sell mobile processors.