# What does one have to consider before upgrading laptops CPU

Tags: laptop, cpu, upgrade

this question is not similar to this, because the other one is about one pc in specific and mine is about any pc.

[Upgrading laptop processor](https://superuser.com/questions/142886/upgrading-laptop-processor)

I have found a intel core i7 octa core (with Intel vpro) in a screen damaged pc so i am interested in upgrade my current i5 dual dual core processor.

I have been researching a little about What does one have to consider before upgrading my laptop´s CPU, and i have found that the only i need to verify is if the new procesor is compatible with the actual socket.

I want to know if this is the only consideration that i must have when installing the processor and what may happen If something goes wrong?

Comment: Check that your CPU is actually replaceable - in laptops they're quite often soldered on.

Comment: yes i have all ready verified that an in both computers the processor can bu removed easily

Comment: The socket, chipset and BIOS would need to be compatible with it. Socket and Chipset are easy enough to verify, but the BIOS is going to be a lot more difficult.

Comment: you also need to make sure you buy thermal paste and scrape the old stuff off of the heatsink

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things to check before upgrading a CPU in a laptop:

- Does the BIOS/Firmware support the CPU that you want to put into your laptop?
- Does the chipset & driver support the CPU you want to  use?
- Does the soxket type on your motherboard match?
- is your current CPU fixed in place (is it user replaceable)?

Considerations while installing:

- possibly voiding any warranty you have left
- you must earth yourself (get an earthing band) to prevent damage to your old and new kit as well as the motherboard
- get replacement thermal grease/paste and make sure all the old stuff is thoroughly removed and discarded
- if you have to reverse the install, ensure that you replace the thermal paste for the old CPU regardless
- Update BIOS, Chipset drivers BEFORE you upgrade

Possible fallout from a bad install

- you may damage your new CPU - you should be able to reinstall the old one.  Make usre you are earthed
- you may damage the old CPU - lets hope your new one works.  Make sure you are earthed
- you may damage both CPUs - you need to get one of them replaced (hopefully under warranty)
- you may damage your motherboard - time for a new motherboard/laptop
- new CPU doesn't work and reads as "not supported" - you've either forgotten to update your BIOS/Chipset or have damaged the new CPU.  Reinsert the old one, do a driver/bios update and try again.  If it still fails, time for a new CPU.

This is far from exhaustive but will hopefully give you something to go on.